# Selecting column with UUID type returns syntax error in C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a column which type is UUID:

```
const std::wstring Select = L"SELECT OptionID FROM OptionsSet WHERE OptionID = ?";
// Create query object
query->addUUID(some_option_id);
query->execute();
```

After execution I am getting

> Error number SqlState=42000 NativeError=102 ErrorMsg=[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.

I suppose '?' is being replaced with UUID like this:

```
OptioID = 70fc92c2-6fd9-4727-8b29-f55b8d6fb07c
```

but instead I guess it should have been

```
OptioID = '70fc92c2-6fd9-4727-8b29-f55b8d6fb07c'
```

I have tried to add that punctuation mark: `L"SELECT OptionID FROM OptionsSet WHERE OptionID = '?'";`, but it didn't help.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: There's no `@P1` in your SQL. Are you sure that error is coming from this query?

Comment: @Barmar I suppose `@P1` is something internal in the SQL and as it can't parse the string properly it outputs an internal error message where `@P1` string exists.

Comment: No the driver replaces each `?` with a named parameter, in this case `@P1`. Parameters don't get *replaced* with a piece of text which is the value of the parameter, they get parsed and the data is bound directly into the parse tree, so `''` don't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the issue: I forgot to put semicolon at the end of the query. So, it should be:

```
const std::wstring Select = L"SELECT OptionID FROM OptionsSet WHERE OptionID = ?;";
```

Comment: I don't think that should matter unless you concatenate another string to this.

Comment: @Barmar So, my current string (which actually works) now is:
`const std::wstring Select(L"SELECT 1 FROM OptionsSet WHERE OptionID = ?;");` I don't think it is because of I replaced `OptionID` with `1`